# Can CKEditor Advanced Content Filter (ACF) allow html comment tag?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Im looking to use CKEditor for a tool that will let users assemble html content from a set of predefined plugin widgets that put placeholder content onto the page. This seems very doable, however I want my html source to contain comments that I will embed flags that I will use to process and replace placeholder content with the needed actual content. It seems that the ACF filter will likely remove any elements that are not configured as allowedContent if the user were to go back and forth with the source button. And I'm not certain it won't remove it as it is added to the current content and moved around. http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf

I'm I correct that this would become an issue and if so
can anyone show me an example of how I can configure the ACF allowedContent to  keep a html comments in a block like this:

```
<hr><!-- this is my comment -->
<b>test</b>
<!-- this is my end comment --><hr>
```

with out losing the comment in the finial html output? I also do not want to disable filtering with the CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true; even if that would work.
Thanks

Comment: I should add, I tested with the demo two ways. If I switch to source view I can past a comment block in and it switches back and forth fine and the comment does not seem to be lost. However, if I copy the block from another browser window and past it into the editor, then the b tag is transformed into string and the comments are removed. Since the plugins are integrated with now with ACF, I sort of suspect that the test where I cut and pasted the content is closer to what will happen when the widget is executed via editor.insertHtml.

Comment: I thinking I'm going to use div tags to identify my placeholder elements, I should be able to wrap my widget block with those without effecting formatting and it will be easier to use a DOM parser in the back end, so my question here for me is mute. But I'm still curious.

Comment: Why not [Placeholder Plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder)?

Comment: The placeholder plugin is a simplified concept of what I need in the snip-it. I need to embed id so that the html created and be post process and essentially mail merged from existing metadata.The user who creates the html need to pick from existing fields. So I'm looking at a widget development project and I need to be sure that all of the capabilities are supported. I will likely be looking at the placeholder widget code for some help :)

Comment: were you ever able to find a solution to this?